# Tools to measure Angular performance

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, profiling

Can someone please suggest any tools (free or paid version) which measure the Angular performance  ?
I was looking response time of API's which call via Angular to backend API. Also if tool can provide performance stats report then would be great. Also, the tool can be used in QA and Production environment to measure the performance

For ex:  Avg Load time, Rebooting time, API response time

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Angular DevTools is probably the way to go for you: https://angular.io/guide/devtools#devtools-overview

You can also profile your application using flame-graphs and load time and also get insights on change detection or memory usage.

API response time can also be seen in the network tab of your browser. It is usually not important for Angular DevTools, because this is done asynchronously and does therefore not have an impact on the angular performance itself. If you want to have the whole image from enduser point of view, you can probably get some insights by using Lighthouse (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lighthouse/blipmdconlkpinefehnmjammfjpmpbjk?hl=de).